# Является ли историзмом слово "динозавр"?

Tags: лексика

Можно ли считать историзмами названия вымерших животных и растений? Ни один учебник не даёт ответа на этот вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, слово *динозавр*, безусловно, не историзм. Важно понимать, что историзм — это слово, рожденное и использовавшееся в эпоху, когда и явление действительности, обозначаемое им, существовало. Термин *динозавр* был введен в XIX в. Р. Оуэном, а самих динозавров тогда, конечно, не было.

Нельзя сказать общо, являются ли историзмами названия вымерших видов; каждое слово — отдельная история.

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить о лексическом разборе слова **динозавр**, его следует отнести к активному словарному запасу русского языка, ведь значение слова известно всем и оно активно употребляется всеми. Мало того, у него появились новое значение и производные образования:

а) значение (перен.) «неуклюжий, большой человек» исконно (ср. слон, медведь, баран и т. п. в переносно-метафорическом обозначении человека);

б) производные слова: динозаврик, динозавровый.

Слово не относится к устаревшим - ни к архаизмам, ни к историзмам, несмотря на то, что живых представителей с этим названием нет. Ископаемые останки их до сих пор находят, их фотографируют, о них говорят, так что слово употребляется, и достаточно активно.

С точки зрения социально-диалектной сферы распространения это лексика ограниченного употребления, является термином, в отдельных словарях есть помета зоол., но второе значение (по отношению к человеку) является общеупотребительным.

С точки зрения происхождения это заимствование, о чём говорит словарная статья этимологич. словаря:

**Диноза́вр** - Заимствовано  в конце XIX в. из англ. яз., где является неологизмом Р. Оуэна, образованным путем сложения греч. deinos «огромный, ужасный» и sauros «ящерица».

Comment: Ещё чаще, кажется,  "динозавр" употребляется в другом переносном значении — ретроград.

Comment: Ну да, точно. Так что новые значения появляются, значит, слово живо.

Comment: Людмила, но ведь не всякий историзм — устаревшее слово. Кажется, у вас не вполне аккуратная формулировка.

Comment: Я исхожу из термина лингвистики. Устаревшая лексика представлена историзмами и архаизмами. Историзмы - устаревшие слова, обозначают предметы, явления, вышедшие из современной жизни. Есть, правда,  семантические историзмы – это слова, существующие в современном русском языке, но имеющие устаревшие значения. Например: крепость – крепостное право, безглагольный– безмолвный, визитка – мужской удлинённый пиджак.

Архаизмы – устаревшие слова, вышедшие из активного употребления и имеющие синонимы, которые употребляются в современном русском языке.